# Get children from flat list

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've got a flat list of items in a ObservableCollection. These items have the properties item.Id and item.Parent.Id.
I've been given the id of the parent (top level), now with this id I need to iterate through the list and find the children of this parent. Each child can only have one parent, a parent can have multiple childs.

How can I do this effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var childrenOfParent = theCollection.Where(item => item.Parent.Id == parentId);
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

Given that you have a hierarchical dataset, I would personally make a routine that checks to see if a given item has a specific item as a parent recursively, like so:

```
bool HasParent(Item item, int parentId)
{
    if (item.Parent == null)
        return false;
    else if (item.Parent.Id == parentId)
        return true;
    else
        return HasParent(item.Parent, parentId);
}
```

Given this, you could use:

```
var childrenOfParent = theCollection.Where(item => HasParnet(item, parentId));
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to put this in my description but the thing is, children of the parent can also contain children of their own and so on.

Comment: This just gets the child at one level. Childs can contain childs of their own and so on and this piece of code doesn't get them. At least I think it doesn't or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it, however, if anyone can optimize/refactor this code into something more efficient please let me know and I'll mark your reaction as an answer. As long as I learn :).

```
        foreach (var item in myitemlist) // first put the top level parent in the queue
        {
            if (parentitem.Id == item.Id)
            {
                filteredChildrenQueue.Enqueue(item);
            }
        }

        while (!stillsearching)
        {
            if (filteredChildrenQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                stillsearching = true;

                return;
            }

            FindParentChild();
        }
```

Keep calling this method and work the first item in the queue

```
    private void FindParentChild()
    {
        foreach (var item in myitemlist)
        {
            if (item.Parent.Id == filteredChildrenQueue.ElementAt(0).Id)
            {
                filteredChildrenQueue.Enqueue(item);
            }
        }

        filteredChildrenList.Add(filteredChildrenQueue.ElementAt(0));
        filteredChildrenQueue.Dequeue();
    }
```

filteredChildrenList will contain the top level parent + all childs it contains.